# Multiple Nested .subscribe in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to show data in my table however the data are dependent on each other. I was able to successfully log the data1.name on my console but when I try to push it into my array(UserData) as my datasource, the table couldn't seem to fetch the data.

this.userApi.GetUser(this.value).subscribe(data => {

```
  if(data.courses.length > 1){
    for(let x in data.courses){
      courseApi.GetCourse(data.courses[x].course).subscribe(data1 => {
      this.UserData.push(data1.name);
      console.log(data1.name);
      });
      //this.UserData.push(data.courses[x].course);
    }
  }else{
     courseApi.GetCourse(data.courses[0].course).subscribe(data1 => {
     this.UserData.push(data1.name);
    })
     //this.UserData.push(data.courses[0].course)
  }

  this.dataSourceMembership = new MatTableDataSource<Course>(this.UserData);
});
```

Comment: try parsing the server data, JSON.parse(yourData)

Comment: A comment about your code. why not using only the loop for this? why you need to check if the length > 1? just use the loop all the time and check if(data.courses.length) { ..yourcode} else return new MatTableDataSource<Course>([]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you're calling

```
this.dataSourceMembership = new MatTableDataSource<Course>(this.UserData);
```

before the GetCourse call completes. Moving this line within the .subscribe calls should fix things.

```
  if(data.courses.length > 1){
    for(let x in data.courses){
      courseApi.GetCourse(data.courses[x].course).subscribe(data1 => {
        this.UserData.push(data1.name);
        this.dataSourceMembership = new MatTableDataSource<Course>(this.UserData);
      });     
    }
  }else{
     courseApi.GetCourse(data.courses[0].course).subscribe(data1 => {
       this.UserData.push(data1.name);
       this.dataSourceMembership = new MatTableDataSource<Course>(this.UserData);
    })
  }
});
```

You can also use [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) to update the table only when all the courses have been retrieved.